# Can and should you style custom elements

Tags: css, aurelia, custom-element

Usually when I create a custom element I wrap it in a `section` or other appropriate HTML element and style that, but this leads the DOM looking like `custom-element > section`.

My question is, is it wrong to remove the `section` and simply treat `custom-element` as the root element and style that?

For example I have a custom element called `tabs`, right now when it's used the DOM ends up looking like `tabs > div.tabs` but I'd prefer to remove the `div.tabs` element if there's nothing wrong with that.

So my question is is it "wrong" to style my custom elements and treat them as any other HTML element, or should I continue to ignore my custom elements completely (even though it's hard to do so when you use `>` and other selectors)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with styling custom elements. To reassure you, custom elements are valid HTML and unless you're supporting an older browser less than Internet Explorer 9, then you'll need to do some extra work to get the browser to recognise them.

I style custom elements all of the time, I even style Aurelia's `<router-view>` custom element as well.

Comment: Just wanted to say I'm really enjoying this, and it makes so much more sense than `section.custom-element-name` all over my code. The DOM looks tidier as well :)

Comment: Oh snap, I noticed something a little annoying though. If a custom element is used as the main router-view Aurelia won't insert the actual `<custom-element>` root element. Obviously this results in all my CSS not targeting the element any longer. I guess for router-views I'll still need a wrapping `section` or similar then...

Answer (score 3):

It's better...

Don't forget that the default CSS `display` for a custom element is `inline`.

So if you want to use `border`, `width`... you should explicitly set `display` (to `inline-block` for example):

```css
custom-element {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.ok {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<custom-element>This is
  <div>ugly</div>
</custom-element>
<hr>
<custom-element class="ok">That's
  <div>fine</div>
</custom-element>
```